# Download files from the download server with the help of php and mvc

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, wcf, download

I have a download server for files.
And I want my users to get the files from the download server.
My download server is Linux.
I want when the user clicks on the download button.
Get the file directly from the download server.
I do not want to use the stream to download ...
I want to connect to the download server via the link and then download it using PHP
My site is with mvc

Thank you, step by step to help me

Comment: Could you please provide code you have so far? And what did you try to accomplish your task?

Comment: @Alexander Actually He posted his code as a new answer

Answer (score -1):

### thank you

Stream stream = null;

```
            //This controls how many bytes to read at a time and send to the client
            int bytesToRead = 10000;

            // Buffer to read bytes in chunk size specified above
            byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];

            // The number of bytes read
            try
            {

                //Create a WebRequest to get the file
                HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Global.UrlVideoPrice + IdCourse + "//" + IdTopic+".rar");




         //Create a response for this request

                HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();

                if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
                    fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;

                //Get the Stream returned from the response
                stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();

                // prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
                var resp = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

                //Indicate the type of data being sent
                resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

//Name the file 
                    resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Topic.fldName + ".rar\"");
                    resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());

```
                int length;
                do
                {
                    // Verify that the client is connected.
                    if (resp.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        // Read data into the buffer.
                        length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                        // and write it out to the response's output stream
                        resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                        // Flush the data
                        resp.Flush();

                        //Clear the buffer
                        buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // cancel the download if client has disconnected
                        length = -1;
                    }
                } while (length > 0); //Repeat until no data is read
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    //Close the input stream
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
```

---

This is my download code.
Now I want the user to get the files directly from the download server.

Do not use site traffic to download the file.
And use server download traffic